# Entire drives have padlock symbol

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, ssd

I've only been using Linux for a few weeks (I'm a recent convert) and in my system, I have several drives, an SSD with Windows 10 on, and an HDD I use for mass storage. Both of these drives have padlock symbols on every folder and file and I can't move files around. I believe that the permissions for both are set to read/write. Any help would be very gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a screenshot of the app you are using where you see these padlocks. To add the screenshot, please upload to imgur.com and add the link in [your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1317771/edit).

Comment: If it happens in case of dual booting with Windows 10, you need to **uncheck turn on fast startup in Control Panel --> Power Options --> Choose what the power buttons do** and then shutdown, not reboot. Once it's done properly you'll be able to access the NTFS partitions normally with read/write permissions. See all the answers to the question below.

Comment: Win 10 fast startup puts Win 10 drives in hibernation, touching files in that state does nasty things to them.

Comment: Thanks, the Windows power thing did it. Curiously even though that option wasn’t checked, checking and unchecking it did the job. Many thanks.

Comment: Beware! Some Windows updates turn "Fast Boot" on again, behind your back.